# iOS RabbitMQ Stop AMQPConsumerThread on app becoming inactive

Tags: ios, rabbitmq

I have an iOS app which requires to send/receive messages on RabbitMQ
I am using the library https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc for integrating iOS with RabbitMQ.

For receiving messages, I am using the AMQPConsumerThread.
Problem is when the user goes out of the app (app becomes inactive), I'd like to sotp the thread and again start it when the user comes back into the app (app becomes active).

I have tried several ways, including invoking the [stop] mehtod, the [tearDown] method but none of them work consistently. sometimes, the connection with rabbitmq gets closed, while most of the times it does not.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This sequence seems to be working for me to toss everything when going inactive. Emphasis on 'seems', I'm brand new to this library too.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AMQPConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AMQPQueue *queue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AMQPConsumer *consumer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AMQPConsumerThread *consumerThread;

self.consumerThread.delegate = nil;
[self.consumerThread closeConsumer];
[self.consumerThread cancel];
self.consumerThread = nil;
self.consumer = nil;
self.queue = nil;
self.connection = nil;
```